# Creating a summary plot from several regression models

Tags: plot, regression, visualization, summary

I am having difficulty in creating the plot like this.

[summary plot of regressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1PDn.jpg)

A~H are different exposures for same outcome. The blue line is estimates/95%CI from univariate models (for example, regression of outcome~A and outcome~B) and the red line is estimates/95%CI from a multivariable model (outcome~A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H).

I tried 'plot_summs' function but it cannot process many univariate models.

Thank you for your help. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: This might help https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html & https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/generating-a-forest-plot.html

Comment: Thank you, solved!